# mysql how to sort based on relationship field

Tags: mysql, sorting, relationships

i stumbled the following problem that i cannot solve
i have the following table in the database

```
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  `Company` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Department` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `DepartmentName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `parentDepartment` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `departments` (`Company`, `Department`, `DepartmentName`, `parentDepartment`) VALUES
(1, '1', 'Company1 Ltd', '1'),
(1, '101', 'Information Technology', '1'),
(1, '10101', 'Hardware', '101'),
(1, '10102', 'Software', '101'),
(1, '102', 'Sales Department', '1'),
(1, '10201', 'Travelling', '101');
COMMIT;
```

basically its a list of departments in the company.  Each department can be "nested" under another using the "parentDepartment" field.

`Department` field is the code of the department.  But the numbering is irrelevant to the "structure".

what i want to achieve can be viewed in the picture bellow.

[image: How i need the data to show]

The question is how to sort this table out and keep the relationships visible?

Thank you

Comment: What is the logic of your order? All I can think of is `order by rpad(Department, 5, 0)`

Comment: If you can review the picture the sort is supposed to order the departments by their parent and after the child.
The problem is that their department code does not matter for the relationship

Comment: If you believe, your question is expressed well enough, then just pick one of the many useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM departments
ORDER BY department;
```

Comment: no this does not work because the relationship between departments is the parent department...